# Unable to use date picker in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to use ngx date picker in my ionic 3 app but I am getting these Error’s

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8100/build/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
vendor.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8100/build/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
vendor.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8100/build/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

My Package.json is

```
{
  "name": "HelloWorld",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.17.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "4.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.11",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {}
    }
  }
}
```

I think this has something to do with version incompatibility but I can’t figure which package is causing it .
Any Help Would be Appreciated.

Comment: mostly 404 http://localhost:8100/build/main.css this location is not available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using my superhero powers, I, Reading-The-Documentation-Man, have deduced that you are using Angular 5.

There is a [note right at the top](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime) which says which version you need to use with that package:

> The picker has been updated for Angular 6+ apps. If you are still using Angular 5, you should install the picker version 5.2.6. `npm install ng-pick-datetime@5.2.6 --save`

But your package says that you are using the criminally high `"ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",`.

Revert your ways, and come back to the light.

Good luck with your development, citizen!

### update

And don't forget to [follow the setup guide for that specific version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime/v/5.2.6) because things changed a lot in Ionic 4.

Comment: did this fix it? :) I'd be really grateful if you would consider upvoting as well otherwise it doesn't count towards my ionic4 tag badge.